# Open a new window from the apps script add-on menu

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have an add-on where I need to redirect to external URL instead loading with Dialog or Sidebar when the menu is clicked.

I have the sidebar code

```
function showContactDialog() {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Website').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setWidth(480).setHeight(380);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Website');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML you can open a new tab (if your browser supports such a thing) but you can't redirect the page.

In your HTML, you can do something like below:

```
<script>
function openPage() {
  window.open('https://google.com', '_blank');
}

window.onload = openPage;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Website.html` place this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function opentab(){
                window.open(LINK_YOU_WANT_TO_OPEN, '_blank');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="opentab()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
function open_new_doc()
{
 var html = '<script>google.script.host.close();'+
            'window.location.href = "'+open_url+'"</script>';

 var html_open = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
 DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html_open, 'Opening New Window...');  
}
```